# Apex generating malformed base64 string

Tags: apex

I'm writing a code where I need to query the product object, get the product image URL, convert the Image in the URL to a base64 string for my other REST input. Here is the code that I'm using.

```
String url='https://myOrg.demo.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0152w000001Jex4';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');
Http binding = new Http();
HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
String encRes=EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);

for (Integer i = 0; i < encRes.length(); i=i+300) {
    Integer iEffectiveEnd = (i+300 > (encRes.length()-1) ? encRes.length()-1 : i+300);
    System.debug(encRes.substring(i,iEffectiveEnd));
}
```

The output that I get is as below.

[image]

when I downloaded the same image and uploaded it online to get the base64 I get it as below. (cropped the bottom part of the output.).

[image]

I'm unable to understand why it is printing `Li4U` strings at the end.

Where am I going wrong in my code and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just query directly? `Document d = [SELECT Body FROM Document WHERE Id = '0152w000001Jex4'];` I'll see if I can replicate this, but it seems silly to burn a callout when a normal query would suffice.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, this fixed my issue mate. Thanks a lot :) Can you please add it to the solution? I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a callout for this, just query the content directly:

```
Document d = [SELECT Body FROM Document WHERE Id = '0152w000001Jex4'];
```